# Why is KL divergence used as a measure of closeness in variational inference?

Tags: kullback-leibler, metric, variational-inference

I am curious why KL divergence is the standard measure of (dis)similarity used in VI while it is not even a proper metric (asymmetric  and does not satisfy triangle inequality).

Comment: Why does it need to be symmetric, given that one of the two arguments is fixed anyway? A benefit of KL is that it’s easy to compute…

Comment: what about the triangle inequality? Isn't it important to satisfy that?

Comment: @Zzy1130 the vast majority of variational problems have a true distribution and an approximating distribution. The KL divergence $K(p,q)$ permits an interpretation of the expected excess surprise when using $q$ as the working model although $p$ is the true model. So symmetry or triangle inequality wouldn’t make sense.

Comment: A valid criticism of variational inference is that it uses $K(q,p)$ instead, which is the wrong direction in view of the above interpretation. But it’s a necessary trade off to make computation tractable. Otherwise, more assumptions are needed

Comment: I think our combined point is: why do you think these properties are needed? Or is it just because you’re more familiar with distances than divergences?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy i guess I am thinking divergence in the same way as Euclidean distances (especially with regard to triangle inequality). Perhaps that intuition does not carry over.